# write file in raw usb c++

Tags: c++, file, winapi, usb

this is my code:

```
int main(int argc, CHAR* argv[]) {

using namespace std;
PVOID data[1024];
DWORD dwBytesRead = 0;
DWORD dwBytesWrite = 512;

HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(L"\\\\.\\E:", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);//open usb 
if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
    printf("Error %x", GetLastError());
    return 1;
}
printf ("created usb hendle\n");
LARGE_INTEGER a = { 50688 };
SetFilePointerEx(hFile, a,NULL,0); //set the pointer to c600 
printf("got usb pointer set\n");
PVOID ToBe = ":) hello this is our file -> ";
if (WriteFile(hFile,ToBe,512 ,&dwBytesWrite,    NULL) == 0)
{
    printf("writeFile error: %x", GetLastError());
    CloseHandle(hFile);
    return 1;
}
printf("write the first string in isb\n");

HANDLE aFile = CreateFile(L"C:\\Users\\h7080y_dxlq\\Downloads\\Video\\88250.mp4", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0); //open the file handle

printf("created mp4 hendle\n");
if (aFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
    printf("Error %x", GetLastError());
    return 1;
}
if (ReadFile(aFile, &data, 512, &dwBytesRead, NULL) == 0) {
    printf("ReadFile error: %x", GetLastError());
    return 1;
}
DWORD dwPos;
printf("checked for read errors in mp4 passed o.k.\n");
while (ReadFile(aFile, data,512, &dwBytesRead, NULL) && dwBytesRead > 0) //read file
{
    dwPos = SetFilePointerEx(hFile, a, NULL, 0); 
    LockFile(hFile, dwPos, 0, dwBytesRead, 0);
    WriteFile(hFile, data, 512, &dwBytesWrite, NULL); // write 512 bit chunk at the time to usb 
    UnlockFile(hFile, dwPos, 0, dwBytesRead, 0);
    a = { 50688+512 }; // promot 
}
printf("write all mp4 to the usb directtly\n");

ToBe = "<- this is the end of file , see you soon :)";
if (WriteFile(hFile, ToBe, 512, &dwBytesWrite, NULL) == 0)
{
    printf("writeFile error: %x", GetLastError());
    CloseHandle(hFile);
    return 1;
}

printf("after end massage \n");



CloseHandle(hFile);
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

I try to take a file (mp4 in this case) , and read it chunk by chunk (512 bit at the time) , take the chunk and write it to usb and so on till end of file .

Now, the problem is:

A the loop never ends.

B that it don't write the file to the USB, it looks like its write on the same spot again and again...

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

```
LARGE_INTEGER a = { 50688 };
while (ReadFile(aFile, data,512, &dwBytesRead, NULL) && dwBytesRead > 0) 
{
    dwPos = SetFilePointerEx(hFile, a, NULL, 0); 
    LockFile(hFile, dwPos, 0, dwBytesRead, 0);
    WriteFile(hFile, data, 512, &dwBytesWrite, NULL);
    UnlockFile(hFile, dwPos, 0, dwBytesRead, 0);
    a = { 50688+512 };
}
```

The first time round the loop you set the file pointer to `50688` and write there. Each subsequent time round the loop you set the file pointer to `50688+512` and write there.

> It looks like it writes to the same spot again and again.

Yes indeed. That's exactly what your code specifies. Your should set the file pointer on `aFile` outside the loop, and let it advance naturally as the file is written. Something like this:

```
dwPos = 50688;
LARGE_INTEGER a = { dwPos };
if (!SetFilePointerEx(hFile, a, NULL, 0))
{
    // handle error
}
while (ReadFile(aFile, data, 512, &dwBytesRead, NULL) && dwBytesRead > 0) 
{
    LockFile(hFile, dwPos, 0, dwBytesRead, 0);
    WriteFile(hFile, data, 512, &dwBytesWrite, NULL);
    UnlockFile(hFile, dwPos, 0, dwBytesRead, 0);
    dwPos += 512;
}
```

Note that your calls to `LockFile`, and the use of a `DWORD` for `dwPos`, means that you cannot write a file larger than 4GB.

It is also far from clear to me that the calls to `LockFile` are needed. Since your original code got the handling of `dwPos` wrong, it's clear that you weren't locking the parts of the file you intended to. It is my belief that you should simply remove them. In which case the code will become:

```
LARGE_INTEGER a = { 50688 };
if (!SetFilePointerEx(hFile, a, NULL, 0))
{
    // handle error
}
while (ReadFile(aFile, data, 512, &dwBytesRead, NULL) && dwBytesRead > 0) 
{
    if (!WriteFile(hFile, data, 512, &dwBytesWrite, NULL))
    {
        // handle error
    }
}
```

You have also omitted large amounts of error checking in this code. I would not be surprised to find that there are a number of other problems with it. I don't particularly want to try to find every single error in your code, and hope that what I have written is enough to help you on your way.

Comment: Thank you . i used lockFile becoase its writefile inside readfile loop and the compiler didnt let to do it in the regular way , only when i used lockFile its went throw

Comment: I cannot understand that at all

Comment: I believe the calls to `LockFile` are a misinterpretation of the [WriteFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365747.aspx) API: *"A write on a volume handle will succeed if the volume does not have a mounted file system, or if one of the following conditions is true: [...] You have explicitly locked or dismounted the volume by using [FSCTL_LOCK_VOLUME](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364575.aspx) or [FSCTL_DISMOUNT_VOLUME](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364562.aspx)."*